# Tableau Dashboard (4 map worksheet) does not display label because too big. Is there a way to display them as they are?

Tags: tableau-api

I have 4 map worksheets. Each are of same size and the text inside each worksheet is not displaying. I cannot increase the size of the dashboard because should remain as it is. How can I show all text in the worksheet?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Go to each sheet and click on the Label Card in the Marks Shelf. Then click the box that says "Allow labels to overlap other marks". See picture.

[image]

Comment: It displays on the worksheet but not on the dashboard. Do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: I just tested this out and it works fine for me.  What version of Tableau are you on?  You can always try removing the sheet from the dashboard and adding it back.  Tableau retains _some_ of the formatting between the sheet/dashboard but not all of it, but I don't think this is one of those (at least for the latest version).

Comment: Yes,I had to resize a bit each maps and the overlapping worked. Thanks